# Difficulty Placing Table in its indended place in my LaTeX Document

Tags: floats, formatting, positioning

I'm struggling with placing a table in my LaTeX document where I intend it to be. I've tried using the `table` environment with `[h!t]` placement, but the table doesn't seem to position where I want it to. Here's a simplified version of my LaTeX code:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section*{Benchmark Results}

\begin{table}[h!t]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l|c|c}
\textbf{n} & \textbf{Single (ns)} & \textbf{Double (ns)} \\
\hline
   ... \\
   ... \\
   ... \\
   ... \\
   ... \\
   ... \\
   ... \\
   ... \\
   ... \\
   ... \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Benchmark results}
\label{tab:benchmark_results}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\section*{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

I've tried using `[h!t]` in the `table` environment, but the table doesn't appear where I expect it, above `Conclusion`.

Can someone guide me on how to properly position this table just below the "Benchmark Results" section and above the "Conclusion" section as intended?

[image]
Thank you for your help!

Comment: The _only_ purpose of the `table` environment is to allow the table to be moved, and `[ht]` doesn't allow it at bottom of a page (no `b`) or on a page on its own (no `p`),  so latex has rather restricted places to place it.

Comment: The image you show is not generated by the code you posted, so it is hard to debug the specific page breaking choice that latex took on your document.

Comment: `\clearpage` before `\section*{conclusion}` would flush the pending floats at that point.

Comment: Given the information you've provided, the only possible conclusion is that *there just isn't enough space on the page* left below the `\section*{Benchmark Results}` header to place the table as well. And, because the only two placement options you're giving LaTeX are `h` ("here") and `t` ("top"), LaTeX has no choice but to place the table at the **t**op of the *next page*. Sure enough, that's exactly what your screenshot suggests is going on. What to do? First, replace the `\begin{center}` directive with `\centering` and get rid of `\end{center}`. Second, replace `[ht!]` with `[htbp!]`.